# How to create and submit package for Qt application

Tags: application-development, packaging, qt

I have an application that I developed in Qt and Ubuntu. Its primary target is Windows but I prefer working in Ubuntu for all sorts of obvious reasons, so I rebuild it using Qt under XP and create an installer that can be used in XP, Vista and W7. Given that it's developed under Ubuntu it seemed a logical step to see if I could also distribute it via the Ubuntu Software Centre. The plan would be to make a small charge for downloading.

I registered in the Ubuntu Application Developer Programme, set up a MyApps account for the application and filled in the application details, marking it as to be uploaded later, but I am confused as to what to do next. According to the 'Publish (Uploading your app)' page, Canonical 'provides the packaging service free of charge', but I would welcome clarification on what I need to submit and how.

As I plan to charge for the package it presumably makes sense not to use an open source license, and this seems to imply that there is no need for me to create a Debian source package. Is this a correct assumption? If so, what would be required in the archive file and how should I submit it, bearing in mind that PPAs are for open-source software (unless I've misunderstood)?

As you can probably tell, software packaging is something I have virtually no experience of, so apologies if I'm asking obvious questions. Also, if this isn't the appropriate forum could you suggest a better place to post this query?

Some advice on what to do about dependencies (such as Webkit) would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a commercial application, just build a tarball containing everything needed to run it, and upload it to the [myapps site](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/). They'll help you through the rest.

Comment: can you post a clickable link to that site?